# Possible to duplicate Every single line?

Tags: notepad++

was just wondering if its possible to dupblicate every line. lets say it looks like this

```
123: 
321: 
54321: 
james: 
michael:
```

is it possible to make it:

```
123:123
321:321
54321:54321
james:james
michael:michael
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a regex Search and replace:

```
Search: ^(.*?).*:$
Replace: \1:\1
```

[image: Search settings]

Comment: @NickWieners It does work. Have you selected "Regular expression" as your Search mode ? (Added screenshot of my search settings, using 7.5.4)

Answer (score 0):

Simple file manipulation like this is pretty easy in C# . . . or VB . . . not sure how to do it in Notepad++

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        using (System.IO.StreamReader inFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(args[0]))
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(args[1]))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                outFile.Write(line);
                outFile.Write(":");
                outFile.WriteLine(line);
            }
            inFile.Close();
            outFile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
DoubleLines.exe input.txt output.txt
```

Comment: The OP asked and tagged for Notepad++.

Comment: Was NOT tagged when I answered :)

Comment: Really? It is the only tag present ad there're no changes since the question has been asked.

Comment: Yes really, there were no tags.  Also the format was all on 2 lines, it was very difficult to read. But, who cares, hopefully Nick has solved his problem.